# Access data from dispatched action using Vuex 4 and Vue 3 Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vuex4

In my application I have a Vuex 4 store and a Vue 3 Composition Api `setup()` method.

In the stores action I use axios to make an api call to get a list of bill payments.

The `getAllBills` action does not live directly in my `Store.js` file, it exists as a module.

```
 getAllBills({ commit }) {
            BillApiCalls.getBills().then(res => {
                commit('GET_ALL_BILLS', res.data)
            }).catch(error => console.log(error))
        },
```

Then in my Bill.vue file I have the `setup()` method and am trying to access the data to be used throughout the same Bill.vue file.

```
setup () {
    //Vuex store
    const store = useStore();
    const billPayments =  store.dispatch('payment/getAllBills').then(res => console.log(res));
}
```

If I check the console from the above `.then()` `res` returns as undefined. If I remove the `.then()` from the `billPayments` declaration and just do:

```
console.log(billPayments)
```

In the console I get

```
Promise {<pending>}.
```

Current Store:

```
import { bill } from './modules/bill.module';

const store = createStore({
    modules: {
        bill
    }
});
```

The endpoint is working, if I use Postman all of my data is returned as expected but I am having trouble figuring out how to access that data using a dispatched action with the composition api.

The Vuex 4 docs don't mention how to actually resolve the promise to access the data to be used throughout the same component.

Answer (score 1):

An action isn't generally supposed to return data it acts on, data is a part of the state and should be accessed there; this is what another answer shows:

```
await store.dispatch('payment/getAllBills')
console.log(store.state.payment.bills);
```

The action doesn't chain promises so it cannot be correctly used. It should be:

```
return BillApiCalls.getBills()...
```

Or prefer `async..await` together with promise to avoid some common mistakes that can be made with raw promises.